# jquery selectors vs vanilla JS selectors with .length returning different results

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given the following HTML page extract.

```
<form>
    <select id="select">
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>           
    </select>
</form>
```

The results of a `console.log();` using `$("#select").length` returns 1 and `document.getElementById("select").length` returns 3. Does anyone have any insight as to why that it? I'm looking to run a loop using the returned value, but I can't understand why it's different. Shouldn't they both return 3? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the jquery case, use: `$("#select").get(0).length`

This will give you the first and only select DOM element in your array list of jquery objects.  This would be the same DOM element as you get with the `document.getElementById("select")` call.

**Update:** To answer comment, the .length call on the select DOM element returns the number of options in the select elements option list.  The .length on the jquery list returns the number of elements matching the selector provided.  `$("#select").get(0)` is the same object as `document.getElementById("select")`.  `$("#select")` is NOT the same object -- it is a list of jquery objects, not DOM elements.

Comment: Note that `$("#select").get(0)` returns the same thing as `document.getElementById("select")` only if there actually is a matching element. (Otherwise the first returns `undefined` while the second returns `null`.)

Comment: Yes, my answer assumes the existence of the element which is in the code provided in the question.

Answer (score 6):

`$(...)` returns a jQuery object, which is an array-like object with zero or more elements.
Its `length` returns the number of elements in the object.

`document.getElementById()` returns a single DOM object, not in any array (as opposed to the plural versions like getElement**s**ByClassName).
Coincidentally, `<select>` elements have a `length` property which returns the number of items in the `<select>`.
That's what you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! How would I get the value of three using jQuery then?

Comment: `$("#select option").length` would give you 3, or check David Fleeman's answer.